# Count of consecutive numbers in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

Suppose I have the following sorted vectors as input:

```
[22]
[22, 23]
[22, 46]
[22, 46, 47]
[22,23,33,44,45,46,55,56]
```

I want the following output which shows the count of consecutive numbers in each vector:

```
1 //edgecase: if there's 1 number it's consecutive)
2 //22, 23 are 2 consecutive numbers
0 //22, 46 not consecutive
2 //46, 47 are 2 consecutive numbers
7 //22,23 (2) 44,45,46 (3) 55,56(2) 7 consecutive numbers
```

My vector will not have duplicates.

What I have so far is:

```
vector<int> numbers;
int consecCount=0;
if (numbers.size()==1)
        consecCount++;
else{
    for (size_t k=1; k<numbers.size(); k++) {
        if (numbers[k]==numbers[k-1]+1) {
            consecCount +=2;
        }
}
```

Of course this method doesn't work for the last array. The solution seems really wrong.

My actual vectors are really large, so prefer any ideas that does not involve using a another vector

Comment: can you clarify what do the output numbers mean?

Comment: are the vectors always sorted?

Comment: So your input is `vector<vector<int>>`?

Comment: Question edited with the meaning of output. Yes, the vectors are always sorted.

Comment: Why not store a bool flag like "more that two in a row" or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
size_t conseccount(const vector<int> &v)
{
    size_t s = v.size();
    size_t ret = 0;
    bool seqstart = true;
    if(s < 2) return 0;
    for(size_t i = 1; i < s; i++)
    {
        if(v[i - 1] + 1 == v[i])
        {
            if(seqstart) ret++;
            seqstart = false;
            ret++;
        }
        else seqstart = true;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Good one  but in case of duplicate values it will return wrong output

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted!! I couldn't figure out what was wrong with my solution. I'm really slow today :(

Comment: @KiranChoudhary Quote from the question: "My vector will not have duplicates."

Comment: @kami Don't worry, happens to everyone :)

Answer (score 2):

### Expected output

```
vector    question  why      my query
1         1         22       Is it 1 or 0.  // I don't understand why 
2         2         22,23   
3         0              
4         2        46,47 
5         7       22,23 44,45,46  55,56
```

That is count the number of entries which are part of sequences such that a[i] = a[i+1]

The key to this is to ensure you count singly, but add one at the end of a sequence.

You need to check whether you are in a sequence `bool bInSequence`, which is `false` initially.  When you transition into a sequence, you set it to `true`.

Then when you leave a sequence, or the loop, you add one.

```
vector<int> numbers;
int consecCount=0;
if (numbers.size()==1)
   consecCount++;
else{
    bool inSequence = false;
    for (size_t k=1; k<numbers.size(); k++) {
        if (numbers[k]==numbers[k-1]+1) {
            consecCount +=1;
            inSequence = true;
        } else if ( inSequence ) {
            inSequence = false;
            consecCount ++;
        }
    }
    if( inSequence == true ) {
        // inSequence = false; //not needed, but logically correct
        consecCount ++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `std::adjacent_find`, you may do something like:

```
std::size_t count_consecutive_sequence(const std::vector<int> &v)
{
    if (v.size() <= 1) {
        return v.size();
    }

    std::size_t res = 0;
    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ) {
        auto e = std::adjacent_find(it, v.end(),
                                    [](int lhs, int rhs) { return lhs + 1 != rhs; });

        if (it == e || it + 1 == v.end()) {
            ++it;
        } else {
            if (e != v.end()) {
                ++e;
            }
            res += distance(it, e);
            it = e;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/dn4dm9)